# C# Instance of child Type is not creating in Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I want instantiate complete class.

1. I have the Type of class which I want to instantiate.
2. `Activator.createInstance(type)` I created Instance.
3. I searched all field of this instance.
4. I have a field which is defined in another assembly so I load that and instantiate it.
5. Again I repeat step 3 and 4 for fields inside that class (nested)
6. I am creating an instance of every type

```
 //in a1.dll
    class class1
    {
       class2 var1;
       //some Method
    }

    //in a2.dll
    class class2
    {
       class3 var2;
       //some Method
    }

    //in a3.dll
    class class3
    {
       //some Method
    }
```

I have to create instance of the entire `class1` type.

Comment: Seems like you have the process down - where are you stuck?

Comment: And where is the queestion??

Comment: Are you getting an exception? I assume, because you did not ask, that `CreateInstance` is throwing some sort of error.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to create a class containing other classes.

Here is what you can do:

- create a class instance through the `Activator` class
- for each property and field type in the current instance, create a sub instance by calling the method you are in and assign the sub instance to the current instance field or property

The following code may help you start getting a handle on this problem, but please read it carefully, as well as the **very important points** under it:

```
public class A
{
    public B MyBProperty { get; set; }
    public C MyCField;
}

public class B
{
    public C MyCField;
}

public class C
{
}

public class Creator
{ 
    static MethodInfo mi;

    static Creator()
    {
        mi = typeof(Creator).GetMethod("Create");
    }

    public T Create<T>()
    {
            var createdType = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        // assign all properties
        foreach (var p in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            try
            {
                var mig = mi.MakeGenericMethod(p.PropertyType);
                p.SetValue(createdType, mig.Invoke(this, null));
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        // assign all fields
        foreach (var f in typeof(T).GetFields())
        {
            try
            {
                var mig = mi.MakeGenericMethod(f.FieldType);
                f.SetValue(createdType, mig.Invoke(this, null));
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        return createdType;
    }
}

// to use it:
var c = new Creator();
var a = c.Create<A>(); // should be instantiated
```

Now for some **very important points**:

- this code is supposed to help you see how you can start, it is very naive
- it doesn't check for infinite loops !!!
- it doesn't cache any creation mechanisms
- it fails if your class cannot be created, for example because it doesn't have a parameterless constructor
- it fails silently
- don't use it!

There are plenty of ways to automagically create objects, and this code is **not** a solid example, merely a starting point: if you want to know more, I would recommend reading the code from [Autofixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) or any other automatic object creation framework. I just hope it will help you look into the right direction.